# Measure distances and areas of geometric shapes

Tags: gratis, linux, osx, images

I'm looking for a software that could assist me in defining geometric shapes over an existing image, define a scale, and display the length and areas of various elements.

For example, let's say I have this picture:

[image]

This is a contrived example, because the scale is already known in this specific case, and I would certainly use a GIS for this, but this serves just as an illustration.

I would like to be able to define the scale using the known dimension of a tennis court, then define a polygon over the pool, then compute its area.

Comment: Do solutions have to work on GNU/Linux *and* Mac OS X, or is one of these OS sufficient?

Comment: It sounds like you are in the business of making pools? Am I correct?

Answer (score -1):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325670/draw-polygon-using-mouse-on-google-maps) in StackOverflow may help serve your purpose.

[Open Layers measure example to calculate distance or area on a map.](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/measure.html)

You could also use [MAPfrappe](http://mapfrappe.com/) and [GMap-Pedometer](http://www.gmap-pedometer.com/) or [Google Planimeter](http://www.acme.com/planimeter/)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this this? Did you use it? What are your experiences? We like our recommendations to be full fledged personal experiences rather then just a bunch of links and "this could work".